# How to access RDS instance which in private subnet from ec2 instance from another private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I want to access RDS instance from ec2 instance. Both are in different private subnet but in same VPC.

Answer (score 4):

Resources within the same VPC (even in different subnets) can certainly access each other.

Check your **security groups**. The best configuration would be to create two security groups:

- **Server-SG:** Allow SSH or RDP access (as appropriate) from `0.0.0.0/0` (or less, if possible, for better security). Associate it to the EC2 instance.
- **Database-SG:** Allow access (eg port 3306 if MySQL) with the Source set to *Server-SG*. Associate it to the RDS instance.

This means that the Database security group will accept incoming connections from any EC2 instance that is associated with *Server-SG*.

When connecting to the database, use the **DNS Name** provided in the RDS console.